# Most metrics are N/A in HDP sandbox on Docker

Tags: macos, docker, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I run the following on macOs Big Sur 11.6:

```
>>> docker start sandbox-hdp  
>>> docker start sandbox-proxy
>>> docker ps
c39991e8397b   hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   7 hours ago   Up 15 minutes   0.0.0.0:1080->1080/tcp, :::1080->1080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1100->1100/tcp, :::1100->1100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1111->1111/tcp, :::1111->1111/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1988->1988/tcp, :::1988->1988/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2100->2100/tcp, :::2100->2100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181-2182->2181-2182/tcp, :::2181-2182->2181-2182/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2201-2202->2201-2202/tcp, :::2201-2202->2201-2202/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2222->2222/tcp, :::2222->2222/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4040->4040/tcp, :::4040->4040/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4200->4200/tcp, :::4200->4200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4242->4242/tcp, :::4242->4242/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4557->4557/tcp, :::4557->4557/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5007->5007/tcp, :::5007->5007/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5011->5011/tcp, :::5011->5011/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6001->6001/tcp, :::6001->6001/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6003->6003/tcp, :::6003->6003/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6008->6008/tcp, :::6008->6008/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6080->6080/tcp, :::6080->6080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6188->6188/tcp, :::6188->6188/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6627->6627/tcp, :::6627->6627/tcp, 0.0.0.0:6667-6668->6667-6668/tcp, :::6667-6668->6667-6668/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7777->7777/tcp, :::7777->7777/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7788->7788/tcp, :::7788->7788/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8005->8005/tcp, :::8005->8005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8020->8020/tcp, :::8020->8020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8032->8032/tcp, :::8032->8032/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8040->8040/tcp, :::8040->8040/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8042->8042/tcp, :::8042->8042/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080-8082->8080-8082/tcp, :::8080-8082->8080-8082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8086->8086/tcp, :::8086->8086/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp, :::8088->8088/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090-8091->8090-8091/tcp, :::8090-8091->8090-8091/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8188->8188/tcp, :::8188->8188/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8198->8198/tcp, :::8198->8198/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->8443/tcp, :::8443->8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8585->8585/tcp, :::8585->8585/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8744->8744/tcp, :::8744->8744/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8765->8765/tcp, :::8765->8765/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8886->8886/tcp, :::8886->8886/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888-8889->8888-8889/tcp, :::8888-8889->8888-8889/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp, :::8983->8983/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8993->8993/tcp, :::8993->8993/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp, :::9000->9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9088-9091->9088-9091/tcp, :::9088-9091->9088-9091/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9995-9996->9995-9996/tcp, :::9995-9996->9995-9996/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10000-10002->10000-10002/tcp, :::10000-10002->10000-10002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10015-10016->10015-10016/tcp, :::10015-10016->10015-10016/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10500->10500/tcp, :::10500->10500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10502->10502/tcp, :::10502->10502/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11000->11000/tcp, :::11000->11000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12049->12049/tcp, :::12049->12049/tcp, 0.0.0.0:12200->12200/tcp, :::12200->12200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15000->15000/tcp, :::15000->15000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15002->15002/tcp, :::15002->15002/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15500->15500/tcp, :::15500->15500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16000->16000/tcp, :::16000->16000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16010->16010/tcp, :::16010->16010/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16020->16020/tcp, :::16020->16020/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16030->16030/tcp, :::16030->16030/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18080-18081->18080-18081/tcp, :::18080-18081->18080-18081/tcp, 0.0.0.0:19888->19888/tcp, :::19888->19888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:21000->21000/tcp, :::21000->21000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:30800->30800/tcp, :::30800->30800/tcp, 0.0.0.0:33553->33553/tcp, :::33553->33553/tcp, 0.0.0.0:39419->39419/tcp, :::39419->39419/tcp, 0.0.0.0:42111->42111/tcp, :::42111->42111/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50070->50070/tcp, :::50070->50070/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50075->50075/tcp, :::50075->50075/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50079->50079/tcp, :::50079->50079/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50095->50095/tcp, :::50095->50095/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50111->50111/tcp, :::50111->50111/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60000->60000/tcp, :::60000->60000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:60080->60080/tcp, :::60080->60080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:61080->61080/tcp, :::61080->61080/tcp, 80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:61888->61888/tcp, :::61888->61888/tcp   sandbox-proxy
bbb8ade50614   hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1   "/usr/sbin/init"         7 hours ago   Up 15 minutes   22/tcp, 4200/tcp, 8080/tcp
```

I then connect to `localhost:8080` using `maria_dev` as username and password. I get the following view:

[image: Ambari dashboard]

Which clearly indicates that nothing is working properly. Is this the expected behavior? If not so, then what should I do to get everything to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected on a fresh start. No services within the Ambari Server/Hadoop cluster start automatically, and there will be no metrics until they do